# How to find the velocity of an object when the gravity force is changing?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

First, the force is $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$.

Then the acceleration at the time one is $\frac{GM}{r^2}$ and $\frac{-Gm}{r^2}$ for both objects.

The question is, will the acceleration at the next time *increase* or *replaced* by the force?

For example, apply $5N$ force in the first second and $3N$ in the second to the body of 1kg. Will acceleration be $8 \frac{m}{s^2}$ or $3 \frac{m}{s^2}$?

Another way to say, does Newton's law find sum of all forces applied over time, or only its change?

Add: the Earth's gravity is $9,8 \frac{m}{s^2}$. It doesn't increase over time, it is constant.

Comment: g is $9.8 m/s^2$ at the surface of the earth. I does not vary with time, but it varies with distance from the centre. So, if you're moving up or down, g will change and, since your movement happens in time, g will then seem to change with time.

Comment: The force on a $1kg$ mass in the constant Earth gravity is $9.8N$, the acceleration is $9.8\frac{m}{s^2}$, and they don't change. In the variable gravity based on the distance $r$, the solution to a similar problem is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361172/change-of-velocity-of-a-falling-object-over-height-acceleration-changing-with-h/361404#361404

Comment: Well I do not want to answer it. But F=ma in Newton's theory. Accelelation will not be increased or replaced, it is the force if the mass is one.

Comment: I asked that because I wanted to run a simulation. But a simple logic showed that a different timer resolution will yield a completely different result.

Comment: Even in Newton's theory, the acceleration is not constant. I wanted to compute an infinite sum. The problem is, if the accel is 10m/s, that does not mean 5m/.5s.

Comment: If I divide time by n, I divide accel by n^2.

Comment: That way, I don't have to compute an infinite sum. I just didn't understood square time concept.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, the radial separation $r(t)$ is a function of time (that can be solved for) and the force, on either body, at time $t$ depends on the the radial separation at time $t$.

This is the Newtonian gravity [instantaneous action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance#Einstein) that is incompatible with special relativity.